# How to remove shadow of input type="submit"?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the `shadow` of an `<input type="submit" value="Login"/>` inside a `form` but I cannot remove it.

On the [official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-background-20100612/box-shadow.src.html) it says that you can set the `box-shadow` property to `none` value.

> Value: `none` | `<shadow>` [ , `<shadow>` ]*

but it does not work.

```css
#loginButton{
 font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.html">
 <input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

I also tried with [!important exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) to see if it is something related about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) but it also does not work.

```css
#loginButton{
 font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ff751a;
 box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.html">
  <input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Am I missing something? Why I cannot remove it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you inspect the element in chrome it shows box-shadow : none for the input element..

Comment: it's `border: 2px outset buttonface`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not box-shadow, it's a special border. Just specify any border and it'll disappear.

```css
#loginButton {
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ff751a;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<form action="login.html">
  <input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @Error404, if it soleved your problem, accept the answer by clicking a check on the left of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I know how Stackoverflow works, but I cannot accept answers yet. Both answers helped to me so I will accept 1 and upvote the other :)

Answer (score 5):

It is border not shadow so you need to do border:none;

```
#loginButton{
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ff751a;
    border:none;
}
```